# Are std::shared_ptrs aware of each other?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

That is, if I don't use the copy constructor, assignment operator, or move constructor etc.

```
int*   number = new int();
auto   ptr1   = std::shared_ptr<int>( number );
auto   ptr2   = std::shared_ptr<int>( number );
```

Will there be two strong references?

Comment: the fact that this code is a problem is the whole reason for `enable_shared_from_this`.

Comment: From my understanding share_from_this() can't be called in the object's constructor. This makes it pretty useless imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there will be two strong references, theres no global record of all shared pointers that it looks up to see if the pointer you're trying to cover is already covered by another smart pointer. (it's not impossible to make something like this yourself, but it's not something you should have to do)

The smart pointer creates it's own reference counter and in your case, there would be two separate ones keeping track of the same pointer.

So either smart pointer may delete the content without being aware of the fact that it is also held in another smart pointer.

Comment: Okay, this is exactly what I want to know. Thanks. Also, this means that the raw "this" pointer is not safe to pass to a weak pointer right?

Comment: Well, you should only be creating weak pointers from shared pointers, not sure how you would end up making a a weak pointer without an instance of a shared pointer?

Answer (score 4):

According to the standard, `use_count()` returns 1 immediately after a `shared_ptr` is constructed from a raw pointer (§20.7.2.2.1/5). We can infer from this that, no, two `shared_ptr` objects constructed from raw pointers are not "aware" of each other, even if the raw pointers are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is asking for crash!

You cannot have two smart pointers pointing to the same actual object, because both will try to call its destructor and release memory when the reference counter goes to 0.

So, if you want to have two smart pointers pointing to the same object you must do:

```
auto ptr1 = make_shared<int>(10);
auto ptr2 = ptr1;
```